# Can't send a POST request with $http in Angular - ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

So I keep getting this `ReferenceError: $http is not defined`, even though I have included `$http` in the controller, which seems to be the most common cause of this error message. I've tried also passing $http into the function itself, but that doesn't solve it.

I feel like I am missing something SUPER obvious, so any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

I've included the entire script, just for clarity's sake. You can see the post request towards the end of the script, inside the `finaliseDay` function.

Thanks!

Here is the error:

```
ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at l.$scope.finaliseDay (http://localhost:8888/goalzy.js:69:12)
    at ib.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:198:303)
    at Dc.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:214:485)
    at l.$get.l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:125:305)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:126:6)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:215:36)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:32:389)angular.js:11607 (anonymous function)angular.js:8557 $getangular.js:14502 $get.l.$applyangular.js:21440 (anonymous function)angular.js:3014 c
```

Here is the HTML first

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="goalzy">
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="goalzy.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="well">
            <h2>Goalzy</h2>

            Dev TODO
            <ul>
               <li>Hook up the API to persist data</li>
            </ul>

            <div ng-controller="TodoController">
               <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining today</span>
               <span>You're at {{percentComplete()}}% completion</span>
               [ <a href="" ng-click="finaliseDay(percentComplete())">finalise day</a> ]
               <ul class="unstyled">
                  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                     <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30"
                     placeholder="add new todo here">
                  <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
               </form>
               <hr>
               <div class="historial" ng-repeat="h in historicalDailyPercentages">
                  <ul>
                    <li>Date: {{h.date}}</li>
                    <li>Percentage of Daily Tasks Completed: {{h.percent}}%</li>
                    <li><div>Tweet it!</div></li>
                  </ul>

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>


</html>
```

And here is the JS:

//Goalzy.js

```
angular.module('goalzy', [])

 .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
   });

  .controller('TodoController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.todos = [];

$scope.historicalDailyPercentages = [];

$scope.addTodo = function() {

  if ($scope.todoText != "") {
    if ($scope.todos.length < 3) {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';   

      //Save to DB

    }
    else {
        alert("You can only have 3 todos per day!");
      $scope.todoText = '';
    }   
  } else {
    alert("you must write something");
  }

};

$scope.remaining = function() {
  var count = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
    count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
  });
  return count;
};

$scope.percentComplete = function() {
    var countCompleted = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      countCompleted += todo.done ? 1 : 0; //Simply calculates how many tasks have been completed
    console.log(countCompleted);
    });

  var totalCount = $scope.todos.length;
  var percentComplete = countCompleted / totalCount * 100;
  return percentComplete;
}


$scope.finaliseDay = function(percentComplete) {
    alert("You're finalising this day with a percentage of: " + percentComplete);
    var today = new Date();
    var alreadyPresent = $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.some(function (item) { 
        return item.date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
               item.date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
               item.date.getDate() === today.getDate();
    });

    //Confirm that nothing has alreayd been posted for today
    if (!alreadyPresent) {
        $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.push({
            percent: percentComplete,
            date: today
        });

        // Simple POST request example (passing data) :
        $http.post('/api/postDailyPercentage.php', {msg:'hello word!'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log("data" + data);
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log("data" + data);
          });

    }
    else {
      alert("You're all set for today - see you tomorrow!");
    }

    console.log($scope.historicalDailyPercentages);
}


  }]);
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Post the complete message and stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Added to the post @JBNizet

Comment: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` - does this work for you?

Comment: Are you sure there's no typos there?

Comment: Looking through thoroughly now @raina77ow

Comment: remove `;` after config block end

Comment: after syntax fixes, there is no error: http://jsfiddle.net/WdVDh/9/

Comment: I'm going to try to get it to work in Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/bt8Fn0jnmIw40HsFpPWK to make sure it's nothing with my setup. Feel free to check it out there!

Comment: So strange, I still get the same error in my console @MosheShaham!

Comment: Can it be my version of Angular?!

Comment: @user2656127 here is with 1.3.13: http://jsfiddle.net/WdVDh/10/   are you using chrome?

Comment: Yes am in Chrome @MosheShaham

Comment: Interestingly, I get a slightly different error in Safari : `Error: Can't find variable: $http`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provider won't be available inside controller with suffix 'Provider', you can do access them by provider name only here it would be `$http` only, also remove `;`
after config initialization

`$httpProvider` setting should be done inside the angular config phase

**CODE**

```
angular.module('goalzy', [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
}]);
 .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    //controller code here
}]);
```

**Note:** For sure you should remove `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';` line from controller

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ck5jtjT8NXiJLO2JYca?p=preview)

Comment: Same issue, even if I set place that config before the controller.

Comment: @user2656127 check now

Comment: Yes, stil the same $http is not defined reference error, when I try execute $http post inside the finaliseDay function.

Comment: @user2656127 have you removed the code using $httpProvider from the controller? Is it the first error you see in the console?

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct, he should remove those line from controller for sure.

Comment: Yep, have removed any $httpProvider calls from the controller, only called in the config now. I'll update my code in original post.

Comment: @user2656127  remove `;` after config initialization

Comment: Done @pankajparkar - same issue with the reference error $http not defined

Comment: @user2656127 http://plnkr.co/edit/1ck5jtjT8NXiJLO2JYca?p=preview actually the code which i gave was missing `]` bracket which closes dependency inject array, check updated answer and plunkr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72461/discussion-between-user2656127-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: @user2656127 what was the issue in the end?

Comment: @MosheShaham lol..she was doing changes in different file and checking different url in browser..you can check chat..that was very funny :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use "$httpProvider" in controller, use $http instead.

e.g.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

As best practice, do not configure provider ($http) in controller. Do it in config section. as below

```
    var app = angular.module('goalzy', []);
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    });

    app.controller('TodoController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.title="scope title";
        //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
}]);
```

see working plunk at http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/4mY4izqc48P8wVQFumZ8/ with your html.

Comment: I actually get the same error in my console on your Plunk (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wyqs0l31fbtvxk/Screenshot%202015-03-07%2012.37.06.png?dl=0)  @Mahesh

Comment: sorry I sent you wrong plunker link. Just updated correct one